# How to plot selected columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot 2 countries only so that I can compare the differences between the two but I don't know how to add it in my code?

df.plot.bar(x='country'); // it shows all the countries and its values

[image]

I just want to show two countries only.

Comment: Can this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter for the two countries. Assuming the two countries are called `country a` and `country b`:

```
mask = (df["Country"] == "country a") | (df["Country"] == "country b")
df[mask].plot.bar(x="country")
```